# Adding 80% horizontal goal line to pivot chart

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts, pivot-table

I have a curve pivot chart to which I'd like to add a goal line with a static 80% horizontal line.

I've seen some people suggest that one could merely add a column with 60% to the dataset. My dataset is however too complex for this to work, and I also find that solution a bit messy, so How can I do this the right way?

Comment: IMO, stay away from Pivot Charts-they impose to much MS formating.  Consider a non-Pivot chart based upon your pivot table data and then you have much more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to accomplish this is to manually set your Y Axis min and max values based upon your data (assuming 0-100%).  Then set your major unit to 0.8 (80%), and your minor unit to 0.1 (10%, or whatever works).  Then use the Major Gridline to act as your 80% goal line.

[image: Pivot Chart Example]

The downside is that you can't label your other minor gridlines (directly as a formating option).  However, if your chart's message is about progress in relation to the goal, this should suffice.

**EDIT:**  I'm not sure why the 30% line didn't show up here, it's in the original, but went missing when I created the .png, so it's not an Excel issue and shouldn't be a problem for the solution.